# Change user input Facebook WP8

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

So I used this code from facebooksdk.net

```
private async void PublishStory()
{
    await this.loginButton.RequestNewPermissions("publish_stream");

    var facebookClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(this.loginButton.CurrentSession.AccessToken);

    var postParams = new
    {
        name = "Facebook SDK for .NET",
        caption = "Build great social apps and get more installs.",
        description = "The Facebook SDK for .NET makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated .NET apps.",
        link = "http://facebooksdk.net/",
        picture = "http://facebooksdk.net/assets/img/logo75x75.png"
    };

    try
    {
        dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await facebookClient.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postParams);
        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbPostTaskResult;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Posted Open Graph Action, id: " + (string)result["id"], "Result", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception during post: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        });
    }
}
```

And when I tap the post button it shares the preset link, How do I change it to a userinput textbox? I do not want to use the system facebook as I am making a facebook client

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I change it to a userinput textbox?" ?

Comment: I mean that it shares a preset link. how do i change it to post a status

Comment: Still cant understand what are you trying to say. Whatever you give in the `link` parameter will be shared, where is the confusion?